# How do I post multiple pictures using a foreach loop via a PHP form?

Tags: php, html, image, forms, foreach

I'm working on this assignment where we need to create a little web app to have someone order what they want on a sandwich, and then put it in simpler terms for whoever gets the order to make the sandwich.

When you pick multiple "extras" all of my images don't show up. Selecting one works fine. Is there some syntax I'm missing in the foreach loop down between output3 and output4 in the PHP?

```
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Sandwich Order</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="sandwichform" method="post" action="sandwichmaker.php">
Size
<select name="size">
    <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
</select><br/>
Meat Type
<select name="meattype">
    <option value="ham">Ham</option>
    <option value="turkey">Turkey</option>
    <option value="beef">Roast Beef</option>
    <option value="salami">Salami</option>
</select><br/>
Bread Type
<select name="breadtype">
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="wheat">Wheat</option>
</select><br/>
Condiments<br/>
<b>Extras:</b><br/>
Tomato<input type="checkbox" name="extras[]" value="tomato"><br>
Lettuce<input type="checkbox" name="extras[]" value="lettuce"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php

$breadtype=$_POST['breadtype'];
$meattype=$_POST['meattype'];
$size=$_POST['size'];
$extras=$_POST['extras'];

if ($breadtype == "white")
{
    $breadimage="images/whitebread.jpg";
}
elseif ($breadtype == "wheat")
{
    $breadimage="images/wheatbread.jpg";
}

$output1="<img src=\"$breadimage\" />";

switch ($size) {
case "small":
    $slices=2;
    break;
case "medium":
    $slices=4;
    break;
case "large":
    $slices=6;
    break;
}

$output2=$slices ." slices of";

switch ($meattype) {
case "ham":
    $meatimage="images/ham.jpg";
    break;
case "turkey":
    $meatimage="images/turkey.jpg";
    break;
case "beef":
    $meatimage="images/turkey.jpg";
    break;
case "salami":
    $meatimage="images/salami.jpg";
    break;
}

$output3="<img src=\"$meatimage\" />";

foreach ($extras as $extra)
{
    $ei="images/" .$extra .".jpg";

    $extrasimage = "<br/><img src=\"$ei\"/>";
}

$output4="with " .$extrasimage;

echo $output1;
echo "<br>";
echo $output2;
echo "<br>";
echo $output3;
echo "<br>";
echo $output4;
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you will always get one image in `$extrasimage` because you are not appending to it but assigning. 
And you probably need to declare `$extraimages` before the for loop so its  in the global scope

```
$extraimages ='';
foreach ($extras as $extra)
{
    $ei="images/" .$extra .".jpg";

    $extrasimage .= "<br/><img src=\"$ei\"/>"; // don't forget the dot
}
```

Comment: Trying it out now. Is the period before the equal sign like a push in an array?

Edit: Totally works. Thanks :]

Comment: the dot adds to the variable it's not an array

Comment: The `.=` means append.  Try this code out for a visual example.  `<?php $dog = "Spot";  echo $dog; echo "<BR>"; $dog .= "ted"; echo $dog; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You are not concatenating the new values with previous ones you will get only the last value in `$output4`

```
foreach ($extras as $extra)
{
    $ei="images/" .$extra .".jpg";

    $extrasimage .= "<br/><img src=\"$ei\"/>";
}
```